# Rubik's Revenge: Double Parity

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

[image]How do I solve this double parity?
Can both be solved at once OR need to solve center parity first and then corner parity or vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the OLL/edge orientation parity, you can hold the orange in front and yellow on top and use

```
Rw U2 Rw x U2 r U2 x' l' U2 l U2 r' U2 r U2 Rw' U2 Rw'
```

to flip the yellow edge.
And to fix the PLL/edge permutation parity, you can use

```
r2 U2 r2 Uw2 r2 U2 Uw2
```

and then solve the cube like a normal 3x3.

Comment: x means which move?

Comment: It's a rotation https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/notation/advanced/